# Python Pandas: Aggregate my indexes into a range of ages

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    age  gender  count
0    10  Female      1
1    10    Male      1
2    12  Female      2
3    13  Female      3
4    13    Male      2
5    14  Female      1
6    14    Male     10
7    15  Female      9
8    15    Male     12
9    16  Female      8
10   16    Male     24
11   17  Female      7
12   17    Male     16
13   18  Female      6
14   18    Male      3
15   19  Female      2
16   19    Male      1
17   20    Male      1
18   21  Female      1
19   22    Male      2
20   23    Male      1
```

I want to aggregate some of the ages together though. Like so:

```
    age     gender  count
0    10     Female      1
1    10       Male      1
2    12     Female      2
3    13     Female      3
4    13       Male      2
5    14     Female      1
6    14       Male     10
7    15     Female      9
8    15       Male     12
9    16     Female      8
10   16       Male     24
11   17-19  Female     15
12   17-19    Male     20
17   20-23    Male      4
18   20-23  Female      1
```

So far I've made bins and then aggreated (? what's the right word here) them with pd.cut and then grouped them, like so:

```
bins = np.array([8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,20,25,30...]) #these bins don't reflect the example I provided
groups = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.age, bins))
```

However, I can't extract the right dataframe from these groups, I feel like it's close, but I don't know how to proceed. When I do `groups.first()` and `groups.last()` I can see that the information I want is there, just obscured. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `groupby` gender as well as the age bins. Aggregate using `sum` and drop the empty rows (`dropna`) to get what you want.

```
groups = df.groupby((pd.cut(df.age, bins), 'gender'))
output = groups.sum().dropna()
```